# Need test to determine if asynchronous I/O is actually happening in C code

Tags: c, asynchronous, lustre

I am new to asynchronous I/O.  I need to get it working in some C and Fortran programs on a Linux system.  I managed to write a little C test code (included below) that reads asynchronously from two files.  The code compiled and ran.  What I am wondering, though, is whether I am truly getting asynchronous I/O, or is the I/O really serial?  The lustre file system I am dealing with is a bit outdated and it is not clear that it actually supports asynchronous I/O, and no one seems to have a definite answer.  So I am wondering are there some timing statements or any kind of output I can add to the code to determine whether it is functioning in a truly asynchronous manner.  I'm betting I'll need much larger files than what I am dealing with to do a meaningful test.  No idea what else I need.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*  for "open()" ... */
#include <fcntl.h>
/* for "bzero()" ... */
#include<strings.h>
/* for asynch I/O ... */
#include <aio.h>
/* for EINPROGRESS ... */
#include <errno.h>
/* for "usleep()" ... */
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024


int main() {

        int fd0, fd1, readstat0, readstat1;
        struct aiocb *ioobjs[2];

        ioobjs[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct aiocb));
        ioobjs[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct aiocb));

        fd0 = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd0 < 0) perror("open");
        fd1 = open("otherfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd1 < 0) perror("open");

        bzero((char *)ioobjs[0], sizeof(struct aiocb));
        bzero((char *)ioobjs[1], sizeof(struct aiocb));

        ioobjs[0]->aio_buf = malloc(BUFSIZE+1);
        if (!ioobjs[0]->aio_buf) perror("malloc 0");
        ioobjs[1]->aio_buf = malloc(BUFSIZE+1);
        if (!ioobjs[1]->aio_buf) perror("malloc 0");

        ioobjs[0]->aio_fildes = fd0;
        ioobjs[0]->aio_nbytes = BUFSIZE;
        ioobjs[0]->aio_offset = 0;
        /* Don't forget this!  With list I/O, there is no
         * particular function call to make.  You have to
         * tell what you want to do via this member of
         * your aiocb struct:
         */
        ioobjs[0]->aio_lio_opcode = LIO_READ;
        ioobjs[1]->aio_fildes = fd1;
        ioobjs[1]->aio_nbytes = BUFSIZE;
        ioobjs[1]->aio_offset = 0;
        ioobjs[1]->aio_lio_opcode = LIO_READ;

        readstat0 = aio_read(ioobjs[0]);
        if (readstat0 < 0) perror("reading 0");
        readstat1 = aio_read(ioobjs[1]);
        if (readstat1 < 0) perror("reading 1");

        lio_listio(LIO_NOWAIT, ioobjs, 2, NULL);


        /* don't completely understand.  gives system time to
         * "wrap things up".  without this, one of the outputs
         * below (maybe both) will have no output to give.
         */
        usleep(100);

        if ((readstat0 = aio_return( ioobjs[0] )) > 0) {
                printf(">>>\n");
                printf("%s\n", (char *)(ioobjs[0]->aio_buf));
                printf("<<<\n");
        } else {
                perror("return");
        }
        if ((readstat1 = aio_return( ioobjs[1] )) > 0) {
                printf(">>>\n");
                printf("%s\n", (char *)(ioobjs[1]->aio_buf));
                printf("<<<\n");
        } else {
                perror("return");
        }


}
```

Comment: Start by directing diagnostic output to stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man aio`, note that `aio_*` is wholly a `glibc` [userspace] implementation.

So, as mentioned, it has some limitations.

The way to see what's going on, timewise, is to have an event log with timestamps.

The naive approach is to just use [debug] `printf` calls. But, for precision time measurements, the overhead of `printf` can disrupt the real/actual timing. That is, we don't measure "the system under test", but, rather, "the system under test + the timing/benchmark overhead".

One way is to run your program under `strace` with appropriate timestamp options. The `strace` log *will* have information about the *syscalls* used. But, because `aio` is implemented in userspace, it *may* not be able to drill down to a fine enough grain. And, `strace` itself can impose an overhead.

Another way is to create a trace/event log mechanism and instrument your code. Basically, it implements a fixed length ring queue of "trace elements". So, the trace data is stored in memory, so it's very fast.

A standard utility that can help with this is `dtrace`. I've not done this myself, as I've preferred to "roll my own". See below for some actual code I've used.

Then, instrument your code with (e.g.):

```
evtadd(TRACE_HELLO,"hello world");
```

Where `TRACE_*` is from an `enum` you define as you wish.

---

Anyway, here's some event trace code I've used in the past. The event struct can be extended to add whatever extra data you wish to store at an event point.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef long long tsc_t;
typedef unsigned long long u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

// trace buffer element
typedef struct {
    tsc_t evt_tsc;
    pid_t evt_tid;
    const char *evt_name;
    u64 evt_xid;
} evtelem_t;

// trace buffer indexes
typedef struct {
    u32 ring_enq;
    u32 ring_deq;
} evtring_t;

// trace buffer control
typedef struct {
    evtring_t que_ring;
    u32 que_max;
    evtelem_t *que_base;
    pthread_mutex_t que_lock;
} evtctl_t;

evtctl_t evtctl;

// advance queue index [wrap if necessary]
#define EVTINC(_qidx) \
    do { \
        _qidx += 1; \
        if (_qidx >= evtctl.que_max) \
            _qidx = 0; \
    } while (0)

// tscget -- get timestamp
tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    static tsc_t tsczero = 0;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    if (tsczero == 0)
        tsczero = tsc;

    tsc -= tsczero;

    return tsc;
}

// tscsec -- convert timestamp to fractional seconds
double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec;

    sec = tsc;
    sec /= 1e9;

    return sec;
}

// evtptr -- point to trace element
evtelem_t *
evtptr(u32 idx)
{

    return &evtctl.que_base[idx];
}

// evtinit -- initialize trace
void
evtinit(u32 qmax)
{

    evtctl.que_base = calloc(qmax,sizeof(evtelem_t));
    evtctl.que_max = qmax;

    evtctl.que_ring.ring_deq = 0;
    evtctl.que_ring.ring_enq = 0;

    pthread_mutex_init(&evtctl.que_lock,NULL);
}

// evtnew -- locate new event slot
evtelem_t *
evtnew(void)
{
    evtring_t *nring;
    evtelem_t *evt;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&evtctl.que_lock);

    nring = &evtctl.que_ring;

    evt = evtptr(nring->ring_enq);

    // advance enqueue pointer [wrap if necessary]
    EVTINC(nring->ring_enq);

    // if queue full advance dequeue pointer to maintain space
    if (nring->ring_enq == nring->ring_deq)
        EVTINC(nring->ring_deq);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&evtctl.que_lock);

    return evt;
}

// evtadd -- add trace element
evtelem_t *
evtadd(u64 xid,const char *name)
{
    tsc_t tsc;
    evtelem_t *evt;

    tsc = tscget();

    evt = evtnew();
    evt->evt_tsc = tsc;
    evt->evt_xid = xid;
    evt->evt_name = name;
    evt->evt_tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);

    return evt;
}

// _evtdump -- dump queue element
void
_evtdump(evtelem_t *evt,tsc_t *tscptr,FILE *xfinfo)
{
    tsc_t tscprev;
    tsc_t tscnow;
    double elap;
    double delta;

    // get timestamp for this entry
    tscnow = evt->evt_tsc;

    tscprev = *tscptr;
    if (tscprev == 0)
        tscprev = tscnow;

    // get time delta from previous entry
    tscprev = tscnow - tscprev;
    delta = tscsec(tscprev);

    // get elapsed time from start
    elap = tscsec(tscnow);

    fprintf(xfinfo,"%.9f/%.9f %8d %s [%llu]\n",
        elap,delta,evt->evt_tid,evt->evt_name,evt->evt_xid);

    *tscptr = evt->evt_tsc;
}

// evtdump -- dump the queue
void
evtdump(const char *file)
{
    FILE *evtxf;
    evtring_t ring;
    evtelem_t *evt;
    tsc_t tscprev;

    evtxf = fopen(file,"w");
    if (evtxf == NULL) {
        perror(file);
        exit(1);
    }

    ring = evtctl.que_ring;

    // initialize previous timestamp
    tscprev = 0;

    while (ring.ring_enq != ring.ring_deq) {
        evt = evtptr(ring.ring_deq);
        EVTINC(ring.ring_deq);
        _evtdump(evt,&tscprev,evtxf);
    }

    fclose(evtxf);
}
```

Comment: @craig-etsey Wow!  Thanks for sharing all that detail there!  Will certainly give it a look.  Thanks again.